# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON for a shell script result

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

```
             const express = require('express');
             const app = express();
             const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
             const shell = require('shelljs');
             var sys = require('sys')
             var exec = require('child_process').exec;

             app.get('/api/v1/script', (request, response) =>{
                //console.log("HERE")
                var extra = "172.30.82.147 0000023FC160 qam"
                const ls = exec('source /root/chat-box/ip.sh ' + extra, 
                      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                           console.log(`${stdout}`);
                           console.log(`${stderr}`);
                      if (error !== null) {
                            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
                      }
                      });
                console.log("$IP")
                const messages = process.env
                response.json({ ls });

                });
```

This code is supposed to return me an IP but all I get from it is

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify ()
    at stringify (/root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1119:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at app.get (/root/chat-box/server.js:31:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/root/chat-box/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)

but I also cannot print anything to see what is going wrong